# Multidimensional Search in Array By Key Value [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the url value using itag value in the array.
I want to find the url value in the array with the itag value 18 (itag=18).

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$videoId = "EJOnwF8mgXc";
parse_str(file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . 
$videoId), $info);
$streams = $info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',', $streams);
foreach ($streams as $stream) {
parse_str($stream, $data);
print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: Include the relevant code here, please, not in a GitHub gist.  Also, please show what you have tried - there are many existing solutions to this problem, so this is not really new.

Comment: I can't add output text because it includes a lot of links (don't allowed by stackoverflow). @cale_b

Comment: what you want to find?

Comment: add if ($data['itag'] === 18) { echo $data['url']; }

Comment: @miknik It does not working (empty output)

Comment: Looking at the URLs again I notice the itag is included. Just use strpos in your foreach loop to search the url for &itag=18 and if true echo the url

Comment: @AhmetHakanBeşel In your foreach loop: `if ($stream['itag'] === 18) { echo $data['url']; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple "if" statement will do :

```
<?php
$videoId = "EJOnwF8mgXc";
parse_str(file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . 
$videoId), $info);
$streams = $info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',', $streams);
foreach ($streams as $stream) {
    parse_str($stream, $data);
    if($data['itag'] == 18){
        echo $data['url'];
    }
}
```